# code outputting same variable no matter number generated

Tags: python, random

Every time I try to run the code i get "you lost" when i guessed the right number. tried moving stuff around but no solution.

this is my code

```
import random

numgened = random.randint(1,2)

print('Enter your bet amount:')
amtbet = input()
print('You have bet ' + amtbet)

print('Number to bet on:')
numbet = input()
print('You bet on ' + numbet)

print(numgened)
if numgened == numbet:
    print('you won '+ amtbet)
else:
    print('you lost '+ amtbet)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of typing

```
import random

numgened = random.randint(1,2)

print('Enter your bet amount:')
amtbet = input()
print('You have bet ' + amtbet)

print('Number to bet on:')
numbet = input()
print('You bet on ' + numbet)

print(numgened)
if numgened == int(numbet):
    print('you won '+ amtbet)
else:
    print('you lost '+ amtbet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `numbet` variable is a `str` returned from `input()` whereas `numgened` in an `int` from `randint()`.

You have to change `numbet` to an `int`:

```py
numbet = int(input())
print('You bet on', numbet)
```

Comment: That is a better description than the previous one.

Comment: Think about flagging as duplicate when an obvious like this comes ;)

Comment: Yes, except the other answer makes fewer changes to the code from the OP.

Comment: @azro: Yes, I thought about duplicates immediately, but couldn't find one instantly. I keep bookmarks to lots already.